# Why my node.js server shows: MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb

const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion, ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
const uri = `mongodb+srv://{processs.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.az3oh.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });

Comment: I solved this problem. I mistakenly used clone instead of equal in the .env file. After that, I use = and solved my problem.  DB_USER=yourdbname

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused with the mongodb account password and user password. You should use a user password, not an account password. That was the reason for my case.

Comment: I solved my problem. I mistakenly used clone instead of equal in the .env file. After that, I use = and solved my problem. DB_USER=yourdbname. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you using wrong username and password. 1. Open Atlas, 2. Go to "Database Access", 3. Click edit on the Database user, 4. Choose password for authentication method, 5. Click edit password, 6.Click show in the password field, 7.Click autogenerated secure password, 8.Don't press copy button for copy, but use manual selection via mouse and copy the text via  keyboard command, 9.Click update user below

**const uri = `mongodb+srv://[username]:<password>@cluster0.yfafd.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;**

Comment: I solved my problem. I mistakenly used clone instead of equal in the .env file. After that, I use = and solved my problem. DB_USER=yourdbname. Thanks